# Merge Array by one of its value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to filter from two different arrays based on following array named = **timeArray**

```
["13:37", "13:36", "13:35", "13:34", "13:33", "13:32"]
```

first array looks like this .. **array1**

```
[
[23323.25,23323.65,23313.25,23315.05,97,62,"13:36"],
[23315.05,23315.2,23314,23315,8,9,"13:37"]
]
```

second array looks like this .. **array2**

```
  [
 
    [23310,23310,23300,23300,0,0,"13:34"],
    [23309.75,23343.1,23305,23323.25,0,0,"13:35"],
    [23296.5,23310,23294.65,23309.8,0,0,"13:30"],
    [23308.35,23310,23301,23306.15,0,0,"13:31"],
    [23308,23309,23292.5,23299.55,0,0,"13:32"],
    [23299.55,23310,23294.15,23310,0,0,"13:33"],
    [23310,23310,23300,23300,0,0,"13:34"],
    [23309.75,23343.1,23305,23324.65,0,0,"13:35"],
    [23308,23309,23292.5,23299.55,0,0,"13:36"]
    ]
```

Based on **Timearray** elements, First should check array1 and then array 2 6th element and expected result should look like

```
  [
    [23308,23309,23292.5,23299.55,0,0,"13:32"],
    [23299.55,23310,23294.15,23310,0,0,"13:33"],
    [23310,23310,23300,23300,0,0,"13:34"],
    [23309.75,23343.1,23305,23324.65,0,0,"13:35"],
    [23323.25,23323.65,23313.25,23315.05,97,62,"13:36"],
    [23315.05,23315.2,23314,23315,8,9,"13:37"]
 ]
```

I tried something like below

```
var finalarray = [];
for(var key in timeArray)
{
  var timer = timeArray[key];
  for(var key in array1)
  {
    arraytime1 = array1[key][6];
    if(timer == arraytime1)
    {
      finalarray.push(arraytime1);
    }
  }

  for(var key in array2)
  {
    arraytime2 = array2[key][6];
    if(timer == arraytime2)
    {
      finalarray.push(arraytime2);
    }
  }
}
```

But `"13:36"` is added two times...Also if the element based on **timerArray** is not present  it should be null... also is there any better way to do it ? I feel like it takes much resource to process... Thank you.

Comment: You didn't explain how the result array should be calculated from the first two array. If there is a match in both array1 and array2, which one should you add to the result?

Comment: please add stacksnippets to show the actual result.

Comment: @gbalduzzi , it is based on the timeArray elements and 6th elements of first two arrays

Comment: I clearly understand that you can match the elements from array1 and array2 to the timeArray looking at the 6th element. But it is not clear what you should do if the same time reference is present in both `array1` and `array2`, as `13.36` in your example. You should keep the one in `array1`? You should sum them? You should keep the bigger one? I don't know

Comment: please add the wanted result. btw, it is not advisable to iterate an array with `for ... in` loop instead of takinging elements with either an index or with `for ...of`.

Comment: yea array 1 is the priority !! ignore the one in array 2 if present in array1.. if not present in array 1 use the one in array 2... if not present in both .. it should be null or something like [0,0,0,0,0,"13.00"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an object for keeping the fist array for each time and map the result.

```js
const
    timeArray = ["13:37", "13:36", "13:35", "13:34", "13:33", "13:32"],
    array1 = [[23323.25, 23323.65, 23313.25, 23315.05, 97, 62, "13:36"], [23315.05, 23315.2, 23314, 23315, 8, 9, "13:37"]],
    array2 = [[23310, 23310, 23300, 23300, 0, 0, "13:34"], [23309.75, 23343.1, 23305, 23323.25, 0, 0, "13:35"], [23296.5, 23310, 23294.65, 23309.8, 0, 0, "13:30"], [23308.35, 23310, 23301, 23306.15, 0, 0, "13:31"], [23308, 23309, 23292.5, 23299.55, 0, 0, "13:32"], [23299.55, 23310, 23294.15, 23310, 0, 0, "13:33"], [23310, 23310, 23300, 23300, 0, 0, "13:34"], [23309.75, 23343.1, 23305, 23324.65, 0, 0, "13:35"], [23308, 23309, 23292.5, 23299.55, 0, 0, "13:36"]],
    times = [array1, array2].reduce((r, array) => {
        array.forEach(a => r[a[6]] ??= a)
        return r;
    }, {}),
    result = timeArray
        .sort()
        .map(time => times[time] || [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, time]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you want

```js
const base = ["13:37", "13:36", "13:35", "13:34", "13:33", "13:32"]
const arrayA = [
  [23323.25,23323.65,23313.25,23315.05,97,62,"13:36"],
  [23315.05,23315.2,23314,23315,8,9,"13:37"]
]
const arrayB = [
  [23310,23310,23300,23300,0,0,"13:34"],
  [23309.75,23343.1,23305,23323.25,0,0,"13:35"],
  [23296.5,23310,23294.65,23309.8,0,0,"13:30"],
  [23308.35,23310,23301,23306.15,0,0,"13:31"],
  [23308,23309,23292.5,23299.55,0,0,"13:32"],
  [23299.55,23310,23294.15,23310,0,0,"13:33"],
  [23310,23310,23300,23300,0,0,"13:34"],
  [23309.75,23343.1,23305,23324.65,0,0,"13:35"],
  [23308,23309,23292.5,23299.55,0,0,"13:36"]
]

// const expectedResult = [
//  [23308,23309,23292.5,23299.55,0,0,"13:32"],
//  [23299.55,23310,23294.15,23310,0,0,"13:33"],
//  [23310,23310,23300,23300,0,0,"13:34"],
//  [23309.75,23343.1,23305,23324.65,0,0,"13:35"],
//  [23323.25,23323.65,23313.25,23315.05,97,62,"13:36"],
//  [23315.05,23315.2,23314,23315,8,9,"13:37"]
//]

const res = base.sort().map(time => {
  return arrayA.find(subArray => subArray[subArray.length - 1] === time)
    || arrayB.find(subArray => subArray[subArray.length - 1] === time)
    || null
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: While this solution works, it is absolutely not efficient. You have a time complexity of O(n^3)

Comment: The only way to make it faster with this input is directly check the last element of the subArrays, which I can edit. Other than that, it wont be better with array inputs

Answer (score 2):

I would modify the arrays in the following format to obtain a much faster access:

```
{
  "13:34": [23310,23310,23300,23300,0,0]
}
```

Then find the appropriate array for each time item.

Code:

```js
const timeArray = ["13:37", "13:36", "13:35", "13:34", "13:33", "13:32"]

const array1 = [
  [23323.25,23323.65,23313.25,23315.05,97,62,"13:36"],
  [23315.05,23315.2,23314,23315,8,9,"13:37"]
]

const array2 = [
  [23310,23310,23300,23300,0,0,"13:34"],
  [23309.75,23343.1,23305,23323.25,0,0,"13:35"],
  [23296.5,23310,23294.65,23309.8,0,0,"13:30"],
  [23308.35,23310,23301,23306.15,0,0,"13:31"],
  [23308,23309,23292.5,23299.55,0,0,"13:32"],
  [23299.55,23310,23294.15,23310,0,0,"13:33"],
  [23310,23310,23300,23300,0,0,"13:34"],
  [23309.75,23343.1,23305,23324.65,0,0,"13:35"],
  [23308,23309,23292.5,23299.55,0,0,"13:36"]
]


const values1 = {}
array1.forEach(item => {
   values1[item[6]] = item
})

const values2 = {}
array2.forEach(item => {
   values2[item[6]] = item
})

const result = []
timeArray.sort().forEach(time => {
   let itemResult = [0,0,0,0,0,0, time]
   if (values1[time]) {
     itemResult = values1[time]

   } else if (values2[time]) {
     itemResult = values2[time]

   }
   result.push(itemResult)
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

in my opinion you can do like this

```js
var finalarray = [];
for(var key in timeArray)
{
    var timer = timeArray[key];
    for(var key in array2)
    {
        arraytime2 = array2[key][6];
        if(timer == arraytime2)
        {
           finalarray[arraytime2]=array2[key];
        }
    }

    for(var key in array1)
    {
        arraytime1 = array1[key][6];
        if(timer == arraytime1)
        {
            finalarray[arraytime1]=array1[key];
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) collection to have `O(1)` while mapping the items. So we can sort `timeArray` and then just `map()` items:

```
const unique_1 = new Map(array1.map(s => [s[6], s]));
const unique_2 = new Map(array2.map(s => [s[6], s]));

const result = timeArray
                  .sort()
                  .map(time => unique_1.get(time) || unique_2.get(time));
```

An example:

```js
const timeArray = ["13:37", "13:36", "13:35", "13:34", "13:33", "13:32"]

const array1 = [
  [23323.25, 23323.65, 23313.25, 23315.05, 97, 62, "13:36"],
  [23315.05, 23315.2, 23314, 23315, 8, 9, "13:37"]
]

const array2 = [
  [23310, 23310, 23300, 23300, 0, 0, "13:34"],
  [23309.75, 23343.1, 23305, 23323.25, 0, 0, "13:35"],
  [23296.5, 23310, 23294.65, 23309.8, 0, 0, "13:30"],
  [23308.35, 23310, 23301, 23306.15, 0, 0, "13:31"],
  [23308, 23309, 23292.5, 23299.55, 0, 0, "13:32"],
  [23299.55, 23310, 23294.15, 23310, 0, 0, "13:33"],
  [23310, 23310, 23300, 23300, 0, 0, "13:34"],
  [23309.75, 23343.1, 23305, 23324.65, 0, 0, "13:35"],
  [23308, 23309, 23292.5, 23299.55, 0, 0, "13:36"]
]

const unique_1 = new Map(array1.map(s => [s[6], s]));
const unique_2 = new Map(array2.map(s => [s[6], s]));

const result = timeArray
                  .sort()
                  .map(time => unique_1.get(time) || unique_2.get(time));

console.log(result)
```

Comment: What is the advantage of `\`${s[6]}\`` instead of simply `s[6]` ?

Comment: @gbalduzzi there is no advantage, I just thought that the type of the 6 element is not `string`. Thanks for the great comment. I've edited my reply.